# Why doesn't this base 10 number $x \mod 2^y$ work for converting base 10 to binary

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, binary

Okay I tried to convert 1 million to binary by dividing by a power of 2 and taking the remainder and dividing that by a power of 2 and so on and I got this:
1111010000100100000
Google says 1 million in binary is:
11110100001001000000

Why is mine with the modular arithmetic 19 bits and the google search for 1 million in binary coming up with 20 bits? Do they take it 1 step further to the half's place or something?
Okay here is how I did it:

$1000000 \mod 2^{19} = 475712$ so 1

$475712 \mod 2^{18} = 213568$ so 1

$213568 \mod 2^{17} = 82496$ so 1

$82496 \mod 2^{16} = 16960$ so 1

$16960 \mod 2^{14} = 576$ so 01

$576 \mod 2^9 = 64$ so 00001

$64 \mod 2^6 = 0$ so 001000000

Comment: You didn't show your work, so it's hard to know why your answer is missing the final 0. Note that one million is $10^6$, so is divisible by $2^6$, so its base-2 representation must end with 6 zeroes.

Comment: Note also that $2^{19} \le 1000000< 2^{20}$, so 1000000 written in base 2 will have 20 bits, just as $10^3 \le 1732 < 10^4$ and 1732 has 4 digits in base 10.

Comment: oh so I didn't have that 2^0 digit at the end I just ended with 2^1

Comment: You have to include the 2^0 digit or else even and odd numbers come out looking the same!